# php template class does not works

Tags: php

Hi I'm having problem with my php template class.the problem is when I open index.php file it does not show anything.I'm not sure but I think the problem is with the template class
**template.php:**

```
<?php
class Template {
    protected $template;
    protected $vars = array();
    public function __construct($template){
        $this->template = $template;
    }
    public function __get($key){
        return $this->vars[$key];
    }
public function __set($key, $value){
    $this->vars[$key] = $value;
}
public function __toString(){
    extract($this->vars);
    chdir(dirname($this->template));
    ob_start();
    include basename($this->template);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
}
?>
```

**frontpage**:

```
<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>
test
<?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

index.php :

```
<?php 
require 'ini.php'; 
$template = new Template('templates/frontpage.php');
echo $template;
?>
```

ini.php :

```
<?php
session_start();
function __autoload ($class_name){
    require_once('libraries/'.$class_name'.php');
}
?>
```

**Note**:the frontpage.php works correctly.

Comment: Is there any errors on your page visible? If not, make sure there is an error reporting on: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've put your code in my local web server and checked for apache error logs (which is what you should have had done) and here is the error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''.php''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /var/www/html/template/ini.php on line
>   4

the problem are :

```
require_once('libraries/'.$class_name '.php');
```

instead of

```
require_once('libraries/'.$class_name . '.php');
```

when i corrected it, there was another error:

> PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'libraries/Template.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in
>   /var/www/html/template/ini.php on line 4

So it looks like all your classes inside the libraries directory should have their first letter of file name upercase.

rename

libraries/template.php

with

libraries/Template.php

Note: you should replace the function "require" with "require_once" to avoid multipe inclusion issues.